# Can I use a pure transitive verb as an Intransitive Verb?

Tags: grammar, terminology, transitive-verbs

Please let me know, whether my following sentences are correct or not?

1. Electrons are generated across the channel.
2. Electrons generate across the channel.
3. Electrons generate an electric field across the channel.

**Is my second sentence correct?**  If yes, why is it so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Generate" is used transitively, which makes your second sentence incorrect. ("Generate" what across the channel?) ; Your first sentence is in the passive voice {Active Voice: (Something) generates electrons across the channel } ; Your third sentence is correct as well. (Subject+transitive verb+object+PP).

Comment: @Stockfish Thank you very much for the clarification.